# Sequentially iterate through all the values in a loop and use they

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, for-in-loop

How can i use loop or may be without loop to **Sequentially** iterate through all the **values** and **use they**? My **array** in firebase have 5 items. Now I get this result `print("index - \(index)"`:

```
index - 0
index - 1
index - 0
index - 1
index - 2
index - 0
index - 1
index - 2
index - 3
index - 0
index - 1
index - 2
index - 3
index - 4
index - 0
index - 1
index - 2
index - 3
index - 4
index - 5
index - 0
index - 1
index - 2
index - 3
index - 4
index - 5
```

**And** `print("count - \(self.MyIndex.count)")`:

```
count - 1
count - 2
count - 3
count - 4
count - 5
```

**With my code**:

```
func load() {

    firebaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "MyFirebase")

    firebaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            for snap in snapshot.children {

                let item = FirebaseIndex(snapshot: snap as! DataSnapshot)

                self.MyIndex.append(item)

                print("count - \(self.MyIndex.count)")

                for index in 0...self.MyIndex.count {

                    print("index - \(index)"

                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

What am I doing wrong? how do I get the correct **indexes** same as **count**?

Comment: You have nested the second loop inside the first loop, so you second loop runs once for each item in the snapshot.  You probably want to move the } to put the `for index...` loop outside the `for snap in...` loop

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, it helped me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Youre doing the print inside the MyIndex-Loop, so it prints it everytime (and repeats itself). Maybe try:

```
for index in 0...self.MyIndex.count {

     //do stuff

}
//Take the print operation out of the loop
print("index - \(index)")
```

and see, if the prints work like you want them to.

Comment: Yes, the repeated is stopped. But `print("index - \(index)")` prints is **index - (Function)** and i can't use it.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? print all indices? Try another for loop then:  

`for index in 0...self.MyIndex {
     print("index - \(index)")
}`